# Cypress get specified element with exact text

Tags: javascript, jquery, automated-tests, cypress

I want to get specified element/component type with some text. First problem I encountered is that using .contains('some text') and get(component-name:contains("some text") it's matching more elemements because of partial match. I would like to make it work non-greedy and match component only if there is exact match, nothing in the beggining and noting in the end. I tried to use regex, but it won't work with this .get() css selector syntax.

```html
<component-name>
  ...
  <span>some text</span>
 </component-name>
 <component-name>
  ...
  <span>some text123</span>
 </component-name>
```

To visualise: out of those 2 components I would like to get component 1 as it contains exact match.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what regex you used but I was able to use `^` and `$` to get an exact match.

```html
<div>some text1234</div>
<div>some text</div>
<div>some text</div>
<div>part of some text</div>
```

```js
cy.contains(/^some\stext$/).should("have.text", "some text");
```

Here is a working example [test](https://github.com/jjhelguero/cypress-examples/blob/main/cypress/e2e/findCheckboxByText.md).

Comment: The issue is that, I want to perform action on <component-name> which is n-level parent of <span>. When I will use contains() I will perform assertions or pass it to next command on span instead of component. This could be acheived by chaining n-times parent() but is riddiculus.

Comment: Ah, perhaps passing 'component-name' as a selector will help capture the element you want.